# Customer session expired after user clicks back button

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-session, sessions

I am building a site in magento. User can able to login and login session was created successfully.

Take this scenario.

1. User added a product to cart (Already Login)
2. Going to the checkout page
3. There he clicks back button on the browser(in both firefox/chrome) and he went to the home page.
4. At that time the session was expired.

Could you please help me to resolve this. Is there any way to maintain the session, even if the user clicks back button or forward button.

Comment: That isn't normal behaviour. You can go back/forwards in Magento without losing your session. Are you sure you aren't using something like Varnish/Cache that is skewing your results.

Comment: I am using Varnish/Redis cache